# How to enable Chrome flags for Chrome Web Store extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am looking for a way to enable `getUserMedia` flag in `chrome://flags` for application in Chrome Web Store. Is there a way so that user does not need to go and switch the flag manually ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any feature that has to be enabled by a flag in Chrome is considered in development or experimental. There is no way to enable them besides a user doing it manually. You should not recommend that general users mess around with flags as they don't have the knowledge or experience to know what they are doing.

Plus since features behind flags can change at anytime without warning, it's only a matter of time before that API changes, breaking your app and then all your users will give your app bad reviews.

Answer (score 0):

Currently works as 
`chrome://flags/#enable-experimental-web-platform-features`